# need help mysql query between 2 dates

Tags: mysql

Need help MySQL query between 2 dates

Table1

```
Date_Start |  Date_End  | No_ID
2014-10-10 | 2014-10-15 |  34
2014-10-20 | 2014-10-22 |  34
```

date between 2014-10-14 and 2014-10-21

And I want for the result

```
No | No_ID | Date_result
 1 |  34   | 2014-10-14
 2 |  34   | 2014-10-15
 3 |  34   | 2014-10-20
 4 |  34   | 2014-10-21
```

Which no 1 and no 2 is base from row 1 at table 1
and no 3 and no 4 is base from row 1 at table 1

and not use "UNION"

Comment: I think you have to clarify.  I don't understand what you're looking for.  Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Explain having `2014-10-10` in the resultset and what is wrong with `UNION`.

Comment: I am lost... very unclear question

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it

```sql
SELECT @rn := @rn + 1 no, no_id, date_result
  FROM
(
  SELECT no_id, date_start + INTERVAL n.n - 1 DAY date_result
    FROM
  (
    SELECT no_id, 
           GREATEST(t.date_start, s.date_start) date_start,
           LEAST(t.date_end, s.date_end) date_end
      FROM table1 t CROSS JOIN 
    (
      SELECT '2014-10-14' date_start, '2014-10-21' date_end
    ) s
     WHERE t.date_start BETWEEN s.date_start AND s.date_end
        OR t.date_end BETWEEN s.date_start AND s.date_end
  ) q JOIN 
  (
      SELECT 1 n UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 
      -- add up to a max possible diff of days between date_start and date_end
      -- or use a tally (numbers) table to avoid UNION here
  ) n 
      ON n.n - 1 <= DATEDIFF(q.date_end, q.date_start)
) q CROSS JOIN 
(
  SELECT @rn := 0
) i
 ORDER BY no_id, date_result
```

Output:

```
| NO | NO_ID | DATE_RESULT |
|----|-------|-------------|
|  1 |    34 |  2014-10-14 |
|  2 |    34 |  2014-10-15 |
|  3 |    34 |  2014-10-20 |
|  4 |    34 |  2014-10-21 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5433c/13)** demo